# Javascript regarding array declaration

Tags: javascript

```js
var Arr_avg = function() {
  var total = 0;
  var arr = [];
  while (true) {
    var inp = Number(prompt("enter value"));
    if (inp !== 0) {
      arr.push(inp);
      var total = arr.reduce(
        (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue
      );
    } else {
      alert("values are" + arr);
      alert("total is" + total);
      alert("average is" + (total / arr.length));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my js program to calculate sum,average of numbers in array and display the array. the code is working fine but i have a doubt, it is as follows

when i declare the empty array `var arr=[];` outside the while loop, the program is working fine, but when i declare it in the `if` block, the program is just printing the last number that is appended to the array when i run it.

I am new to js, is this some global/local variable thing?

please explain

thanks

Comment: You might consider using indentation while writing code, it'll make it a whole lot easier to read and debug, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well.

Comment: Don't think your code should work at all, see `var inp=Number(p\`enter code here\`rompt("enter value"));` -> `SyntaxError`

Comment: If you declare the array within the if block it'll be recreated on each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: @H77 This isn't a scope issue, the scope is the entire function in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `var arr = []` inside the `if` block, you're emptying the array each time through the loop, before you push the input into it. So the array only contains the last input. `var arr = []` can be considered a shortcut for

```
var arr;
arr = [];
```

The first line just declares the variable, and the second line assigns a value to it. If the variable already has a value, that old value is replaced with this to it. So you lose the old contents of the array.

You might have learned that `var` declarations are "hoisted" to the top of the function. That only refers to the declaration part, the assignment is still executed at the place where the declaration is written. So if it's inside the loop, the variable is reinitialized each time through.